# Prevent SELECT on a database during a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I am building a Web API on which I apply some custom security mechanisms. In order to check if an operation is authorized I need to save its changes in the database within a transaction and do a commit or a rollback after.

Here is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Account account)
{
    using (DbContextTransaction transaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        Context.accounts.Add(account);

        Context.SaveChanges();

        // This will do one or several SELECTs on the database to do the verification
        RollbackIfForbidden(transaction, account);

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

What I need is to set an `IsolationLevel` on my transaction that locks the table (or the database) until the transaction is committed or rollbacked. This lock should delay any query done on the database while it is locked ***except*** for those that are sent by the method `RollbackIfForbidden`.

This would allow to prevent people to get erroneous data if they query the database between `Context.SaveChanges();` and `transaction.Commit();` but still accept any query done inside `RollbackIfForbidden(transaction, account);`.

**Edit:**

*User story*

1. The user sends a POST query to create an Account entity.
2. The service begins a transaction and store the account in the database.
3. The database can apply some modifications on the entity (via triggers or constraints).
4. The service query the new account with the changes made by the database.
5. The service checks that the current user has the right to create this specific account (based on the value that the user filled and that the database completed)
6. The service do a commit if the user is permitted, or do a rollback if he is forbidden.
7. The service returns the status of the operation (success or error).

My problem is that between the steps 2 and 6, another user may do a query on the database and get the created account while it may be removed in the step 6.
So I need to lock the database in the meantime but I also need to query the database in step 4 to get the new values of my entity.

Comment: `SaveChanges` method has built in transaction, doesn't it?

Comment: @LeiYang I need to use a specific transaction because I want to be able to do a rollback in case of an error. If the `SaveChanges` method has a built in transaction it is useless for me if I can't access it. But my question is more about locking the database during my transaction.

Comment: can you give us a **user story** why need such transaction?

Comment: @LeiYang I edited my question to add a user story

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_getapplock to set your locking for transaction in sql server

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx